# Can you create a spoiler using just JavaScript and not Jquery?

Tags: javascript

I am learning  Javascript right now, and I under stand its all client side and does not store information like php. I also have seen spoiler codes and all the ones I have seen use jquery. When I use the word "Spoiler" I am referencing something you click to open information ( usually a plus sign) and then to remove the hidden information from view you click it again ( usually its a minus sign).  I was wondering if it would be possible to create a spoiler just using Javascript and nothing else, and if it is possible a small example.

Comment: jQuery can't do anything that JavaScript can't do, because jQuery is "just" a collection of functions written in JavaScript. So the short answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: JQuery is written in Javascript

Comment: jQuery is written with JavaScript, so given that the short answer is: yes, JavaScript can do that.  jQuery just provides abstractions of common tasks and common browser inconsistencies.  So, typically, the jQuery code written without jQuery is much longer and more complex.

Comment: Yes. Target [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it cannot be answered with much more than "yes" (or "no").

Comment: What does this even mean? What's a "spoiler" in this context?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Not being in the black in a game of Roulette of life

Comment: "jQuery can't do anything that JavaScript can't do, because jQuery is "just" a collection of functions written in JavaScript. So the short answer to your question is "Yes"." ------> Thank you for your answer

Comment: Can the down votes be removed I added more information to the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's entirely possible.  You just need to access your events and elements through native javascript.  If you can provide an example of what you're trying to do I can give you some better sample code to get the job done.

```
<head>
  <script>
    docReady = function() {
        var spoilers = document.getElementsByName('spoiler');
        for(var s = 0; s < spoilers.length; s++) {
             spoilers[s].onclick = function(e) {
                 // Prevent the default link action
                 e.preventDefault();

                         // Show the parent element's next sibling
                 var spoilerText = this.parentNode.nextSibling;
                 spoilerText.style.display = 'block';
             }
        }
   }
// Attach docReady function to DOMContentLoaded 
    // (Works in Firefox/Chrome/Safari)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docReady, false);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stories">
         <p>This is the story<a href="#" name="spoiler">Spoiler</a></p><
             p style="display:none">Spoiler Text</p>
         <p>This is the story<a href="#" name="spoiler">Spoiler</a></p><
             p style="display:none">Spoiler Text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

A quick point of advice: learn to use `console.log`, it will be your best friend with native javascript.

Also, if you're wondering why I broke the paragraph line after the opening bracket of the second paragraph it's an issue with the `nextSibling` method.  For the sake of brevity I used simple javascript methods in the example.  You can read about the `nextSibling` issue [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Whitespace_in_the_DOM?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FWhitespace_in_the_DOM).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. In reference to what you said " If you can provide an example of what you're trying to do I can give you some better sample code to get the job done." ....  an example of the spoiler I am referring to would be like the ones seen here : http://iamdentistry.com/faq/

Comment: I wrote a little fiddle that mimics those (though not entireley).  It includes all the HTML, CSS and JS along with an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/K3E7p/

Comment: Hi thank you, I am trying to understand the JS , I get that --> var spoilerButtons = document.getElementsByName('button'); ---> means that    "button" is the name of the object your trying to manipulate with a click of a mouse but next after that what does this mean ? ---> for (var s = 0; s < spoilerButtons.length; s++)  ... ?

Comment: Basically that's just telling the loop how long it needs to run.  `s = 0;` sets the start point and continues until `s` is equivalent to the number of buttons that were found.  The `s++` is the increment statement that tells `s` to add one to itself for every run through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I dont understand something . first "s" is a letter not a number so saying that this loop will run until 0 = s  is confusing since after 0 comes 1 not a letter so that means it will run forever ?

Comment: Well `s` in this case is the variable.  It's cast as an integer so the variable `s` has a value of 0.  The loop then adds 1 to `s`'s value for each time through with the `s++` line.